# Why does my recursion double- function return -nan(ind) instead of x?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, nan

I'm a begginer in C++ programming. I didn't find division by zero and a negative number in sqrt. Why does approx_root() return -nan(ind) instead of x? Help me pls!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double approx_root(double x) {
    double x_prev = x;
    x = ((2 - pow(x_prev, 3)) / 5);
    cout << x_prev << " " << x << endl;

    if (abs(x - x_prev) <= pow(10, -5)) {
        //cout << abs(x - x_prev) << " " << pow(10, -5) << endl;
        return x;
    }

    approx_root(x);
}

int main()
{
    double x=1;
    
    cout << approx_root(x) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwrw1.jpg)

I was waiting for my function to return me x. I don't understand what I can do.

Comment: The image shows the result

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything in the recursive case, leading to undefined behavior

Comment: The function "falls of the end" after the recursive call, without a `return` statement.   For a function that returns a value, that causes undefined behaviour.   You need to make the function return.   One way might be to change the last line of the function to `return approx_root(x);`  - but you'll need to check if it still produces the required result.

Comment: Your compiler should issue a warning for that code, about missing a `return` statement. Please listen to the compiler and what it tells you, and treat all warnings as actual errors.

Comment: And please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that approx_root() didn't return anything... Thanks, I'll take that into account.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   Modern compilers (and even older compilers) are configured by default to NOT give warnings about such things.  It's necessary to enable more warnings (say, via command line options or IDE settings) to get such warnings.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're attempting to find an approximation of a root using a recursive function. There are a couple of issues in your code.

Firstly, in the approx_root function, the recursive call to approx_root(x) is missing a return statement. Secondly, in your main function, you're trying to output the result of approx_root(x) directly without considering its return value properly. Correcting this errors may help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `main()` outputting the return value of a function it calls.